# Almost everywhere pointwise convergence

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, sequence-of-function

I am trying to solve this problem

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of numbers so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin(a_nx)$ exists pointwise almost everywhere on  $\mathbb{R}$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n$ exists.

I tried to use Egoroff's theorem and other things, but I could not solve it.

Comment: Just a thought. If the limit doesn’t exist, than (1) a_n fluctuates (say it has two ‘limit point’) or (2) tends to infinity, then in case 1 lim sin(a_n) fluctuates btwn at least two limits; (In case 2 We need to prove a_n doesn’t tend to infinity regularly (which implies a_n x may be periodic such that sin(a_nx) tends to a limit.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a stronger result: Suppose $\sin(a_nx)$ converges pointwise on a set of positive measure. Then $a_n$ converges to a finite limit.

Proof: Let $E$ be a set of positive and finite measure where $\sin(a_{n})$ converges pointwise.

We first prove $(a_n)$ must be bounded. If not, then WLOG there exist $0<a_{n_1} < a_{n_2} < \cdots \to \infty.$ By DCT we have

$$\tag 1 \int_E \sin^2(a_{n_k}x)\,dx \to \int_E f(x)^2\,dx.$$

The left side of $(1)$ equals

$$\int_E \frac{1-\cos(2a_{n_k}x) }{2}\, dx = m(E)/2-\frac{1}{2}\int_E \cos(2a_{n_k}x)\, dx.$$

Because $a_{n_k}\to \infty,$ the Riemann-Lebesgue lemma shows the last integral $\to 0.$ Hence $m(E)/2=\int_E f(x)^2\,dx.$

On the other hand,

$$\int_0^1f(x)^2\,dx = \lim \int_0^1f(x)\sin(a_{n_k}x)\,dx.$$

The limit on the right is $0,$ again using RL.

We therefore have $m(E)/2=0,$ contradiction. This proves $(a_n)$ must be bounded.

So now assume the bounded sequence $(a_n)$ has the given limit property but $\lim a_n$ fails to exist. Then

$$L=\liminf a_n< \limsup a_n = M.$$

There exist subsequences $a_{l_k}\to L$ and $a_{m_k}\to M.$ It follows that

$$\sin (a_{l_k}x) \to \sin (Lx),\,\, \sin (a_{m_k}x) \to \sin (Mx)$$

for $x\in E.$ We conclude $\sin (Lx)=\sin(Mx)$ on $E.$ Since these are analytic functions, we have $\sin (Lx)=\sin(Mx)$ everywhere. Differentiating then gives$$L\cos (Lx) = M\cos (Mx)$$everywhere. Now plug in $x=0$ to get $L=M,$ contradiction.

Therefore $\lim a_n$ exists.

Comment: why we can assume that $a_n$ is bounded?

Comment: I'm not saying we can make that assumption. With the above I'm only getting part of the way.

Comment: I believe I've taken care of the case $(a_n)$ unbounded.

Comment: I edited my answer to give a stronger result.