# Convergence of $e^{iu_nx}, x \in \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(u_n)_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Suppose that $e^{ixu_n}$ converges to a limit for every $x$
in a set $K$ of strictly positive Lebesgue measure.

So, is it true that there exists $\eta>0,$ such that $\forall 0<x< \eta,e^{iu_nx}$ converges?

Since $\lambda(K)>0,$ then $K$ is dense in $\mathbb{R},$ I don't if this can help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The result follows from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3775900/almost-everywhere-pointwise-convergence/3775956#3775956

Comment: In your link $E,$ doesn't need to have a finite measure

Comment: ?? Does your $K$ have finite measure? And why does this matter?